# Concept of WebView in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

Is there any concept of Webview in Roku like android iOS. I just want open web site through URL.
In Roku document not Webview related information available.

Answer (score 2):

No, Roku SDK does not include web browser component

Comment: #nav banov thanks for reply.i have one more question how can i change ui after call rest api ?. is it possible rest api call without in main class? i main in other class.

Comment: @DEEPAKMITTAL if you change UI in ROKU it's only possible using XML.

Comment: what is your REST API purpose? It is passed ROKU Format DATA.